# Use four CPUs to run a python script

Tags: python, multicore

I'm running a python script that does some operations over a large graph, so I would like to take advantage of the 4 cores of my PC. Watching the task manager I can see that all CPUs are running but the total CPU usage is up to 50%. As I set this PC exclusively to run this script I would like to use  its CPUs as much as possible. Is there a python module or anything that can be set in my OS (windows 7) in order to allow me to do that?

Comment: you will want to read up on the multiprocessing module http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/multiprocessing/basics.html

Answer (score 7):

C Python has a rather generous lock that precludes most threaded operations from truly happening in parallel.  You might want to look at the [Multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module.

Otherwise, you could use a Python implementation that allows for concurrent threading:

- [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/)
- [Jython](http://www.jython.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Have a read through this module:

http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html

for very good work and a more simple example:

http://www.devshed.com/c/a/Python/Basic-Threading-in-Python/

Hope these help!